# One liner to check if element is in the list

Tags: java

I have been working on and off with Java/Python. Now in this situation I want to check if the element is in the list and do stuff...

Python says:

```
if "a" in ["a", "b", "c"]:
    print "It's there!"
```

Does Java provide any one liner for this rather than creating `ArrayList` / `Set` or similar data structure in steps and adding elements to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.asList`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

```
if( Arrays.asList("a","b","c").contains("a") )
```

Comment: The List is just a wrapper around the array, so it's very lightweight.  Of course, "contains" is just going to end up iterating through the array, so what's the point?

Comment: @danben sure, but it's an appropriate one-liner.

Comment: It is a one liner - and you don't have to instantiate collection types manually. +1 from me :)

Comment: yeah, and for one-liners there's no advantage to using O(log n) techniques over O(n). If you're going to reuse checking for inclusion in a large set, use a HashSet, if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: He says a one-liner that doesn't create ArrayList or Set.  This certainly does.

Comment: @danben, he says "in multiple steps"

Comment: (Most of the overhead here is going to be in creating the array, not the `List`.)

Answer (score 18):

There is a boolean contains(Object obj) method within the List interface.

You should be able to say:

```
if (list.contains("a")) {
    System.out.println("It's there");
}
```

According to the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

`Returns true if this list contains the specified element. 
More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at 
least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).`

Answer (score 8):

In JDK7:

```
if ({"a", "b", "c"}.contains("a")) {
```

Assuming the Project Coin collections literals project goes through.

**Edit:** It didn't.

Comment: It's about time.  Hopefully this gets adopted.  I'm tired of the verbosity of Java

Comment: The extra 13 characters probably wont kill you.

Comment: @X_Trust Add your own static contains method with varargs if you're desperate.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using Strings with a separator which does not appear in any element.

```
if ("|a|b|c|".contains("|a|"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
if (Stream.of("a","b","c").anyMatch("a"::equals)) {
    //Code to execute
};
```

or:

```
Stream.of("a","b","c")
    .filter("a"::equals)
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(ignore -> /*Code to execute*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.Arrays.binarySearch to find an element in an array or to check for its existence:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...

char[] array = new char[] {'a', 'x', 'm'};
Arrays.sort(array); 
if (Arrays.binarySearch(array, 'm') >= 0) {
    System.out.println("Yes, m is there");
}
```

Be aware that for binarySearch to work correctly, the array needs to be sorted. Hence the call to Arrays.sort() in the example. If your data is already sorted, you don't need to do that. Thus, this isn't strictly a one-liner if you need to sort your array first. Unfortunately, Arrays.sort() does not return a reference to the array - thus it is not possible to combine sort and binarySearch (i.e. Arrays.binarySearch(Arrays.sort(myArray), key)) does not work).

If you can afford the extra allocation, using Arrays.asList() seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If he really wants a one liner without any collections, OK, he can have one:

```
for(String s:new String[]{"a", "b", "c")) if (s.equals("a")) System.out.println("It's there");
```

*smile*

(Isn't it ugly? Please, don't use it in real code)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Itemfound{ 
        public static void main(String args[]){

                if( Arrays.asList("a","b","c").contains("a"){
                      System.out.println("It is here");
         }
    }
```

}

This is what you looking for. The contains() method simply checks the index of element in the list. If the index is greater than '0' than element is present in the list.

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}
```